# How do I "Ignore" 1/1/1753 when querying less than 90 days against a datetime column?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, datediff

```
select case when [Estimated Return Date] <= DATEDIFF(day, -90, GETDATE()) then 
'90 Days or Less To Estimated Return Date' else '' end as 'Alert', [No_]

from [Rental Header]
where [Estimated Return Date] != '1/1/1753'
```

The problem with this is it eliminates a number of the records I need to see by adding the where clause.

Comment: What is the purpose of that `WHERE` clause, and does any of your data really have anything to do with the year 1753?  Also, I don't think that `1/1/1753` is a valid date literal in SQL Server.

Comment: When no date is added in the [Estimated Return Date] field it defaults in SQL to 1/1/1753.  That date is obviously < 90 from today's date and returns the true argument in the case when.  I'm using this for conditional formatting in a report to display the contract number in red when the contract is 90 days or less from expiring.

Comment: @CraigZirnheld: Just move the `where X` condition into the `case` clause, i.e. `case when ... and not X then ...`? Or did I misunderstand your problem?

Comment: @GrantWinney  Grant, this is to query for contracts that are approaching 90 days or less to a future date.

Comment: Why wouldn't you instead use NULL. 1/1/1753 is a valid date and older than 90 days. You can solve here by moving your expression to case statement but it would be like a bandage rather than a cure.

Comment: If you do not want to restrict the query (thus eliminating a "number of the records") simply remove the line `where [Estimated Return Date] != '1/1/1753'`

Comment: @Heinzi, adding and to the case statement worked.  Believe it or not it's the first time I've had to use and in a case statement.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As a bandage you could do this (better use NULL for 1753):

```
select case when [Estimated Return Date] > '17530101' AND

       [Estimated Return Date] <= DATEDIFF(day, -90, GETDATE()) 
     then '90 Days or Less To Estimated Return Date' 
     else '' end as [Alert], [No_]
from [Rental Header];
```